# Variables not working in included templates (html/template)

Tags: go

The template "head" inserted on "index" template and use one variable {{ .Title }}

Main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
)

var (
    t = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.tpl"))
)

type Page struct {
    Title string
    Desc  string
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    index := Page{Title: "This is title", Desc: "Desc"}
    t.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index", index)
}

func main() {
    router := httprouter.New()
    router.GET("/", Index)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

Index.tpl:

```
{{ define "index" }}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    {{ template "head" }}
<body>
    <h1>Main info:</h1>
    Title: {{ .Title }}
    Desc: {{ .Desc }}
</body>
</html>


{{ end }}
```

head.tpl:

```
{{ define "head" }}

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ .Title }}</title>
</head>

{{ end }}
```

I get this html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>


<body>
    <h1>Main info:</h1>
    Title: This is title
    Desc: Desc
</body>
</html>
```

Variable {{ .Title }} works on site body, but doesn't work in head.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass the variables to the template:

```
{{ template "head" . }}
```